# Convert and save string to binary file in Python

Tags: python, encoding, bluetooth, get, obex

I'm using PyOBEX to exchange binary files (e.g. images etc.) between my computer (Windows 7) and my phone (Android). However, when I use `get()` to get a file from my phone, it arrives on my computer as a `str`. I tried using the `chardet` module to find out what encoding to use to decode it and eventually turn it into a binary file, but it returned `None`. `type()` says that it's a `str`.

The code is the following:

```
import bluetooth
import BTDeviceFinder
import PyOBEX.client

name = "myDevice"
address = BTDeviceFinder.find_by_name(name)
port = BTDeviceFinder.find_port(address)
client = PyOBEX.client.BrowserClient(address, port)
client.connect()
a, b = client.get("pic.jpg")
```

where `a` is the header (that comes with a file sent via OBEX) and `b` is the actual file object. `b` looks something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0ywTLTjb3LaFJaM2hWVEdBakE/view?usp=sharing

The PyOBEX documentation or Python forums say nothing about what encoding is used with `get()`.

Do you know how to turn this string into binary data that can be used with `write()` and then saved in the original file format (i.e. .jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 2.7 strings represent raw bytes (this changes in python 3)

You simply need to save the data to a binary type file:

```
with open('file.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
    handle.write(data_string)
```

Here is a link to the python doc on open:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Note that the "b" represents binary.

Again, this is assuming Python 2.7